# Insert Into Select Get ID From another Table

Tags: sql

I have a DB that we built a few years ago that we're placing into an RDB. I want the following:

```
PlantName  PlantNumber  Customer  ProductNumber  Product
________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________
Loc A      1000         Joe's     123456         Pizza 1
________________________________________________________
Loc B      2000         Jerry's   654321         Pizza 2
```

Which is one table, to go into a new database with `Plants`, `Customers` and `Products` Tables. I have the `Customers` table already worked out:

```
CustomerID    CustomerName
____________________________
____________________________
987           Joe's
____________________________
789           Jerry's
```

And I want the `Products` Table to look as such

```
ProductID    CustomerID    ProductName    
_______________________________________
_______________________________________
123456       987           Pizza 1
_______________________________________
654321       789           Pizza 2
```

So my question is, how can I create an `INSERT` Statement to get the `CustomerID` from the `Customers` Table? I would need to select both from the old `Products` Table and the new `Customers` Table to ge the `ProductID` and the `CustomerID` values.

Comment: Uh, no.  You want a `products` table and a `customerProducts` table -- two reference tables and a table that correlates them.

Comment: You are right. I will want it set up like that. I'm just asking more as a technical SQL question. Because I will need to get two ID's from two different tables. Thanks for the tip, though

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular `INSERT` syntax using a nested `SELECT` statement. See this link for example: [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

```
INSERT INTO Products ( ProductID, CustomerID, ProductName )
SELECT  12345, CustomerID, 'Product name'
FROM    Customers
WHERE   CustomerName = 'name'
```

But as the comment suggests, you'd probably want to create a third mapping table that handles this data for you. One table strictly for customers, one for products, and a third one for purchases/customer product mapping.

You might also be interested in normal forms for databases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form which can help you design your tables in a cleaner, easier to maintain fashion.

Comment: So if I need to get the `ProductID` from the old table, do I just plop a `SELECT` statement or do I need to Join two tables?

Comment: If you need the `ProductID`, then you'd have to join the two tables.

Comment: Okay that's the part I'm iffy about

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT INTO` statement.

```
SELECT A.ProductNumber as ProductID, B.CustomerID, A.Product as ProductName 
INTO Products
FROM Plants as A
INNER JOIN Customers as B
ON B.CustomerName = A.Customer
```

The drawback is if CustomerName is not unique and refers to a different person. 
So the good design is your original table has CustomerId instead CustomerName.