# Using where clause in Insert statement while in CURSOR

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am running this code and am getting this error `ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended`

How would you write this code so this error does not exist? member_addresses_to_remove is a `CURSOR`.

```
 FOR curr_element IN member_addresses_to_remove 
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO schema.tablename(ID,NAME, PHONE_NUMBER)
    VALUES (curr_element.ID, curr_element.NAME,curr_element.PHONE_NUMBER)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM SCHEMA.OTHERTABLE OT
                      WHERE OT.ID = curr_element.ID);                        
  END LOOP;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: change the VALUES for SELECT [your columns] from dual .... It should work

Comment: and maybe you just forgot to remove the WHERE condition in the INSERT statement,

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from?rq=1

Comment: @JorgeCampos I did that and now it is saying ORA-00907 missing right parantheses. I have all closing parantheses. Is this something you are familiar with? Also why does from dual work? What is it doing there?

Comment: Well, I think you didn't remove the parenthesis from your columns? I wasn't clear enough, I wanted to say SELECT your columns without the parenthesis .... :)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect because you are combining a `values` clause with a `where` clause.

Try this:

```
 FOR curr_element IN member_addresses_to_remove 
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO schema.tablename(ID,NAME, PHONE_NUMBER)
    SELECT curr_element.ID, curr_element.NAME,curr_element.PHONE_NUMBER
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM SCHEMA.OTHERTABLE OT
                      WHERE OT.ID = curr_element.ID);                        
  END LOOP;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: It's unlikely you need this loop at all.  You probably write a single INSERT INTO statement instead of having the cursor at all.  But you haven't shown that code and this should fix your immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you! This works. Can you explain to me why dual works? How is that grabbing my data from the current element in the cursor?

Comment: About dual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm

Comment: You can't put anything after a values clause, so you need a table to select from.  Dual has one row.

Comment: Hi @WW. as you already commented I would also add to your answer the insert select statement so the OP can choose the right approach :) +1 anyways

Answer (score 0):

Insert statement syntax is wrong, pls check below example.

```
INSERT INTO trg_tbl (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM src_tbl
WHERE col4 = myvale;
```

test SQL by executing single SQL statement in SQLPlus then add it procedure

Comment: I am trying to insert data from a CURSOR with the where clause going to look into another table to see if one one the values exists there or not. If it does then I do not want to insert that data.

Comment: Hi, Ok I got it. but I think you can make it all in single SQL statement without using a cursor.