# Issue with INSERT/SELECT SQL in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I get a syntax error between the INSERT part and SELECT part. I have no iddea why.

```
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE  ( '2018-08-13', MEMBER_PROFILE.MOW_ID, 0, MEMBER_PROFILE.FUNDING, NULL,NULL,NULL, 20, NULL)

SELECT MEMBER_PROFILE.MOW_ID 
FROM
MEMBER_PROFILE
WHERE MEMBER_PROFILE.FUNDING IN (6,7,8,10,18)
AND MEMBER_PROFILE.MOW_ID NOT IN (SELECT SCHEDULE.MOW_ID FROM SCHEDULE WHERE BKFST > 0 AND DATE ='2018-08-13');
```

Comment: You miss the `;` after the insert statement

Comment: You use `MEMBER_PROFILE.FUNDING` in your insert but you do not include that field in your select statement

Comment: @Jens I think he want to use `insert` with `select` as one statement

Comment: What are column name in SCHEDULE table?
You can do :
insert into schelule (col1, col2, col3)
select '2018-08-13', MEMBER_PROFILE.MOW_ID, 0, MEMBER_PROFILE.fundind from .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to merge the bracketed part of the INSERT with the result of the select:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE
SELECT '2018-08-13', MEMBER_PROFILE.MOW_ID, 0, MEMBER_PROFILE.FUNDING, NULL,NULL,NULL, 20, NULL
FROM
MEMBER_PROFILE
WHERE MEMBER_PROFILE.FUNDING IN (6,7,8,10,18)
AND MEMBER_PROFILE.MOW_ID NOT IN (SELECT SCHEDULE.MOW_ID FROM SCHEDULE WHERE BKFST > 0 AND DATE ='2018-08-13');
```

See the documentation - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html - for a reference for the correct syntax.

P.S. I would also advocate that you explicitly list the field names in the Schedule table so there's no problem with which field will get inserted into which column.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE
(Column1, Column2 ...etc
SELECT ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include a ; symbol after each query/sentence.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( ------ );
SELECT ..... FROM TABLE WHERE ...;
```