# How to insert multiple values from one table into another table?

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables in SQL Server:

**Users Table:**

```
[user_id]       [other_columns]
```

**Permissions Table:**

```
[permission_id] [other_columns]
```

**Users_Permissions Table** (a many-to-many join table):

```
[user_id]       [permission_id]
```

I need to apply the same permissions to multiple users at once and insert the `user_id` and `permission_id` into the `users_permissions` table.

For example, I need to link **all** users in the `users` table to `permission_id` #5. I can do this individually with this code:

```
INSERT INTO users_permissions (user_id, permission_id) VALUES (1, 5);
```

But how would I do that in a batch for all users in the `users` table?

**Bonus:**
Is it possible to also include multiple `permission_id` for each of those users? So if I want to apply insert 8 permissions for all 50 users, how would I do that?

Comment: I think this could be [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971/685760)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO users_permissions (user_id, permission_id) 
SELECT UserId, 5
FROM User
```

To do multiple you can use cross join. Below will insert permission 1 to 4 for each user

```
 INSERT INTO users_permissions (user_id, permission_id) 
 Select UserId, PermissionId
 From User
        Cross Join permissions 
 Where PermissionId in (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: The `cross join` should be for the `permissions` table. If you can update your answer to show that, I'll accept it as this worked beautifully.

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the table name!

Comment: Thank you for your help!