# Stored Procedure for quick add

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures, parameters

Hello I'm trying to create a stored procedure to quickly add contacts. I have multiple tables and joined them accordingly. My parameters are StudentEmail,EmployeeName,ContactDetails, and ContactType. I'm having trouble with my insert into statement if anyone can help me out.

```
 Drop Procedure if exists usp_addQuickContacts
 Go
 Create Procedure usp_addQuickContacts
   @StudentEmail nchar(50) = NULL, 
   @EmployeeName nchar (50) = NULL, 
   @ContactDetails nchar (50) = NULL, 
   @ContactType nchar(50)  = NULL

AS
Begin
Insert Into StudentContacts
(
    ContactID,
    StudentID,
    ContactTypeID,
    ContactDate,
    EmployeeID,
    ContactDetails
            )
 From StudentInformation inner join StudentContacts 
 On StudentInformation.StudentID = StudentContacts.StudentID 
 Inner Join Employees 
 On StudentContacts.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID

End
Go
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is missing a `select`:

```
Insert Into StudentContacts (ContactID, StudentID, ContactTypeID, ContactDate, EmployeeID, ContactDetails)
    select . . . 
    From StudentInformation si inner join
         StudentContacts sc
         On si.StudentID = sc.StudentID inner join
         Employees e
         On sc.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID;
```

The `. . .` is for the columns, presumably from the underlying tables.  You need to fill in that part.