# How to insert dynamic query into table using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i need to insert my dynamic query which i am generating and saving into sql-server database table, but without where condition its working fine but with where condition its giving me error, please anyone can help me on this.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tablename] ([DataQuery],[DataQueryName],[EditedDate],[LastUsedDate],[UserId])
 VALUES ('SELECT * from tablename WHERE tablename.UID < '10' AND tablename.status = 'Active' ORDER BY Id'
       ,'aa',GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'1541')
```

Comment: What error? BTW, Do INSERT with SELECT instead, skip VALUES.

Comment: Please check your quotes ' in the DataQuery value.

Comment: SELECT * from tablename WHERE tablename.UID < '10' AND tablename.status = 'Active' ORDER BY Id            this is my first parameter which should insert into [DataQuery] column

Comment: Is rewriting the SQL statement possible or is it a bogus statement? AS stated it look like a [insert select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from). without the need of escaping the querry

Comment: Are you storing queries in a column? This really looks like that is what you trying to do. Why???

Comment: Show us C# code how do you do the sql query.

Comment: And when you get an error stating "its giving me error" is worthless unless you also provide the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the single quotes with single quotes in your SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tablename] ([DataQuery],[DataQueryName],[EditedDate],[LastUsedDate],[UserId])
 VALUES ('SELECT * from tablename WHERE tablename.UID < ''10'' AND tablename.status = ''Active'' ORDER BY Id'
       ,'aa',GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'1541')
```

Comment: Correct, but when i need to run that inserted query it won't work.

Comment: Have you tried it?  When you pull that query back out of the database it will have only one quotation mark.  The `''` tells SQL Server that this is a quotation mark in the string, *not* the end of the string.

Comment: Correct, thanks its working, when i am pull the query back

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the single quotes in your WHERE clause need to be escaped. Try replacing single-quotes in your query with \' to escape the quote. Example:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tablename]
([DataQuery],[DataQueryName],[EditedDate],[LastUsedDate],[UserId])
 VALUES ('SELECT * from tablename WHERE tablename.UID < \'10\' AND tablename.status = \'Active\' ORDER BY Id'
       ,'aa',GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'1541')
```