# how to denote a duplicate value in insert?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is an insert statement.

`insert into tableA (c1, c2, c3) values ( v1, v2, v3)`

It happens v1 and v2 are the same value as `(select x from tableB where x='y')`

I want to avoid add `select` twice in the insert query. Is there a way like `insert into tableA (c1, c2, c3) values ( (select x from tableB where x='y') a, a, v3)`?

This is not a hard question but it's not a duplicate either. The difference is so obvious. Sigh. Editor. Learn to read.

Comment: Possible dublicate question. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from?r=SearchResults&s=4|305.1100

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into tableA (c1, c2, c3) 
    select x, x, 'testvalue'
    from tableB
    where x = 'y';
```

Comment: wait. Why sql complains "not enough values"?

Comment: @CCNA . . . It shouldn't.  You are inserting into three columns and selecting three values.

Comment: got it. I tried to use mixed statement as `values ((select x,x from tableB), 'testValue')` which caused the problem.