# Substring to divide and update a field in the same syntax

Tags: select, sql-server-2005

sorry in advance if my question is already exists.

I'm a sql beginner and have an issue about how can i update a field with 'Select' where one field already exists in the datatable (Table1) and the another field update by the sintax.

```
Select
Business,
Month,
Opens
From Table2
```

I would like in the same syntax to be able to do the sends / opens calculation and update the field named 'Open Rate'

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJA49.png)

Today i have the table1 with

Month -- Send -- Opens -- Open Rate

May -- 100 -- --

The table 2 have

Opens - Month

5 -- May

My goal: update the table 1 with the table 2 with the open rate (Send/Opens):

Month -- Send -- Opens -- Open Rate

May -- 100 -- 5 -- 20

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: unfortunately i can not use Insert, i need to do it with SELECT. It's a limitation of the software I use

Comment: Can you use an `UPDATE` or `MERGE`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server

Comment: No. Just the Select :/

Comment: You can't insert, update, or otherwise change a row or data in a DB with using just a `SELECT`, so it unfortunately sounds like you're SOL. What software are you using? It might be a permissions thing or maybe you need an update or an alternate to your software to make this work.

Comment: What is your expected output? Please post that as text rather than image.

Comment: My expect is the field 'Open Rate' is populated. I updated the question.