# Insert multiple lines with a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

With this stored procedure (SQL Server):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[fill_table1]
    @CreatedBy nvarchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        [IdExchangeRate] = NEWID(),
        [ExchangeRateCode] = 'EUR',
        [ExchangeRatePeriodStartDate] = period,
        [ExchangeRatePeriodEndDate] = EOMonth(period),
        [ExchangeRateValue] = B.Value,
        [CurrencyCode] = A.[Currency Code],
        [CreatedBy] = 'string',
        [CreatedAt] =  GETUTCDATE()
    FROM
        [TempExchangeRates] AS A
    CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT
             period = TRY_CONVERT(date),
             Value = TRY_CONVERT(float, value) 
              ......) B
END
```

I want to insert this output (+100rows) into another table (table2). I tried but it inserts just one row.

Comment: i edit my question. thank u

Comment: What does "for now it's insert just one line" mean? There is nothing being inserted anywhere in this code. It is just a select statement.

Comment: yes iit' s just a select when i add insert  into[table2] Values ( , ,) it's insert just one line with NULL

Comment: Well....if you are using VALUES it will insert one line. That is how it works. You would want to use the select statement here INSTEAD of  a VALUES clause. Share your insert statement and I can show you.

Comment: Or check out the documentation for the INSERT statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Or this question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: But  i have one question plz, using insert into.. value(@) those values must be declared!! in my case i  don't need  to insert those values because i alredy had them ... this is why i did'nt understand how i do that

Comment: for the second link, me i don't have a table it's just the output of a stored procedure.

Comment: ur right it's works ..thank u so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for @Sean Lange comment. It helped me so much.

I add that before select

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2]
       ([column1]..
       ,[columnsn]
       )
```