# Inserting value in middle table in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, foreign-keys, syntax-error

I am trying to insert a value in a middle table, which is created by having two other tables relationship many to many. So this middle table has 2 foreign keys(idProduct and idWarehouse), one for each table and an additional row(storage). So I have trouble inserting in this third row. 
It gives this error:

```
    Result: near "SELECT": syntax error
At line 1:
INSERT INTO ProductsInWarehouse (idProduct, idWarehouse, storage) 
VALUES 
(SELECT
```

This is my code:

```
    INSERT INTO ProductsInWarehouse (idProduct, idWarehouse, storage) 
VALUES 
(SELECT id FROM Products
WHERE nameProduct = 'cheese',
SELECT id FROM Warehouse
WHERE nameWarehouse = 'Vegas', 
'10')
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from). Note such insert statements do not use `VALUES`, that's probably your error. The answer is db agnostic, but [SQLite documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm) says the same.

Comment: I do not understand, in the links you provided they also use VALUES and also put SEARCH queries in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the queries must be enclosed inside parantheses:

```
INSERT INTO ProductsInWarehouse (idProduct, idWarehouse, storage) VALUES 
(
  (SELECT id FROM Products WHERE nameProduct = 'cheese'),
  (SELECT id FROM Warehouse WHERE nameWarehouse = 'Vegas'), 
  '10'
);
```

This will work if theses queries return always only 1 row, so both columns `nameProduct` and `nameWarehouse` must be unique.
 
The statement can also be written without the `VALUES` clause, with `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO ProductsInWarehouse (idProduct, idWarehouse, storage) 
SELECT
  (SELECT id FROM Products WHERE nameProduct = 'cheese'),
  (SELECT id FROM Warehouse WHERE nameWarehouse = 'Vegas'), 
  '10';
```

Comment: Yeah, this was it :) Thanks a lot!