# T-SQL: INSERT IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: t-sql, sql-insert, not-exists

I have two tables:

`people`

```
| peopleID | Lastname | Firstname |
| -------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1        | Smith    | Marc      |
| 2        | Doe      | John      |
| 3        | Davidson | Terry     |
| 4        | Meyer    | Todd      |
| 5        | Richards | Abe       |
```

`customers`

```
| customerID | Lastname | Company             |
| ---------- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1          | Davidson | Wonderproducts Inc. |
| 2          | Meyer    | Banana Inc.         |
```

Now I want to insert all elements of the table `people` to the table `customers`, except the ones, where the lastname equals the lastname in `customers`.

So at the end `customers` should look like this:

```
| customerID | Lastname | Company             |
| ---------- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1          | Davidson | Wonderproducts Inc. |
| 2          | Meyer    | Banana Inc.         |
| 3          | Smith    |                     |
| 4          | Doe      |                     |
| 5          | Richards |                     |
```

I already tried around this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM customers WHERE Lastname = (SELECT Lastname FROM people))
INSERT INTO customers (Lastname) VALUES (SELECT Lastname FROM people)
```

Comment: Why do you need to use an `EXISTS` here? A `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM...WHERE`  (emphasis on the `WHERE`) seems far simpler. An `EXISTS` would stop any rows being inserted, not just the ones you don't want.

Comment: @Larnu ... and that looks like a great answer to me ^ ^

Comment: I'm not sure, however, we need another duplicate answer of "how to `INSERT` data from one table to another" though, @TimBiegeleisen ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: I've always wondered about the duplicate threshold.  Is it an _exact_ dupe?  The data are different.  Maybe you're right...

Comment: Personally, @TimBiegeleisen , I don't think that the data or design need to be identical, but the idea. For example, at the end of the day asking "how to create a delimited list in SQL Server" is the same regardless of if your table is called `Sales`, `Customers` or `Schools` and the column is called `Product`,`CustomerName` or `HeadMaster`; use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: As a SQL beginner: I totally understand that there are several questions similar to this. But in this specific case I do not know how to skip those entries, I described in the post. How would I be able to exclude (partly) existing rows using `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM...WHERE`?
I cannot do something like `INSERT INTO Customers (Lastname) VALUES (SELECT Lastname FROM People WHERE Lastname != (SELECT Lastname FROM Customers))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```sql
INSERT INTO customers (Lastname)
SELECT P.Lastname
FROM people P
    LEFT JOIN customers C ON C.Lastname = P.Lastname
WHERE C.customerID IS NULL
```