# Import values from temporary table to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm joining 3 tables:

```
SELECT 
catalog_product_entity.entity_id AS product_id,
catalog_product_entity.sku,
customer_entity_varchar.entity_id AS customer_id,
customer_entity_varchar.value,
customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id,
import_tmp.customer,
import_tmp.grp,
import_tmp.qty,
import_tmp.price
FROM catalog_product_entity
    INNER JOIN import_tmp 
    ON catalog_product_entity.sku = import_tmp.sku
    INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar 
    ON import_tmp.customer = customer_entity_varchar.value OR import_tmp.grp = customer_entity_varchar.value
    WHERE customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 139 OR customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 140
```

Currently, I'm fetching the data, build a new array and insert it into my final table.

```
INSERT INTO final_table(`c_id`, `p_id`, `price`) VALUES (customer_id, product_id, price);
```

However, I wonder if it's possible to do this in one go, so basically directly from the temporary table?

Comment: There is an ANSI SQL approach for this which you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from ... a word of caution though. Make sure this is done outside of a production environment first. Clone a portion of all your tables to a local database or somewhere safe. Never run something like this directly in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO final_table (c_id, p_i`, price)
    SELECT cev.entity_id AS customer_id,
           cpe.entity_id AS product_id,
           it.price
    FROM catalog_product_entity cpe JOIN
         import_tmp it
         ON cpe.sku = it.sku JOIN
         customer_entity_varchar cev
         ON cev.value IN (it.customer, it.grp)
    WHERE cev.attribute_id IN (139, 140);
```

Note that I introduced table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.  And `IN` is easier to follow than repeated `OR` conditions.

Comment: Just one follow up question, in case I'll ever need it. Is it possible to INSERT ... SELECT into 2 tables? So basically into final_table_A and final_table_B ?

Comment: @hardy123480 . . . MySQL doesn't support inserting into two tables in one `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO final_table(`c_id`, `p_id`, `price`) 

SELECT 
customer_entity_varchar.entity_id AS customer_id,
catalog_product_entity.entity_id AS product_id,
import_tmp.price
FROM catalog_product_entity
    INNER JOIN import_tmp 
    ON catalog_product_entity.sku = import_tmp.sku
    INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar 
    ON import_tmp.customer = customer_entity_varchar.value OR import_tmp.grp = customer_entity_varchar.value
    WHERE customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 139 OR customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 140
```

Above code will do that. Just select to rows you want to insert into final_table.