# Select specific rows and columns from an MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm currently doing a student attendance program using c# and MySQL.

I created a database called `std_info` where it keeps students information and there are `nibm_id, nic, name,address,number,batch` in that table

2nd table name is `std_att` to get student attendance and the columns are `nibm_id, nic, name, batch`

What i want is to retrive only `nibm_id, nic, name, batch` from `std_info` table to `std_att`
The primary key is `nibm_id`

here is what i was trying to do so far

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into std_att (nibm_id, nic, name, batch) SELECT * (nibm_id, nic, name, batch)  FROM `std_info` where nibm_id like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```

Please show me a way to do this. Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: @MarceliWac answers only for SQL Server

Comment: May I ask. Why are you have duplicate names in the tables. So far I only see that std_info is having some extra info compare to std_att. There for I don't see the use of std_att. 

I would also advice you to just full out write the words for attribute names an table names. this makes it way harder to read and understand.

Comment: @SachinthaSenanayake, are you saying you are using SQL Server, or that the question I suggested only solves your problem when it's running on SQL Server? Asking, because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971/5683522) cleary states that it works for MySQL (which I assumed you're using).

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into std_att (nibm_id, nic, name, batch) SELECT nibm_id, nic, name, batch  FROM `std_info` where nibm_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```

There are obviously a lot better ways to get this done, and the above is vulnerable to SQL injections etc, but I can understand if this is for a simple quick piece of work.

Like some of the users have said, don't have duplicate columns in `std_att`  table since they are already in the main table `std_info`

I would also try to find the `nibm_id` before the insert bit, to validate in-app and not let the db freak out on it's side (if `nibm_id` can't be found)