# I want to use the INSERT statement to insert values that come from the SELECT statements in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to use the INSERT statement to insert values that come from the SELECT statements in PHP

the table of student is not get the data

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student(academic_major, promo, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, (?));";
$stmtt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmtt, $sql)){
    header("Location: add_student_forum.php?error=sqlerrorstudent");
    exit();
}else{

    $id = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtt, "sss", $academic_major, $promo, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtt);
    header("Location: add_student_forum.php?signup=success".$id);
    exit();
}
```

when i execute it shows me this header header("Location: add_student_forum.php?signup=success".$id); in the url
and i dont know why the table is empty after

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: The statement was successfully prepared fact does not mean that it will be successfully executed. The query text looks like errorneous but preparable.

Comment: here I need the id from the user table to use it like foreing key

Comment: I want to implement this SQL statement in PHP:

Comment: execute the select, get the id then use it in the insert statement

Comment: INSERT INTO student(academic_major, promo, user_id) VALUES ('txt', '2018', (SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = 'exp@gmail.com'))

Comment: okey kevin i will try it

Comment: You don't bind SQL as a parameter. Bind the data as parameter and put the SELECT SQL in the prepared statement SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't bind SQL as a parameter. Bind the data as parameter and put the SELECT SQL in the prepared statement SQL

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student(academic_major, promo, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = ?);";
$stmtt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmtt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtt, "sss", $academic_major, $promo, $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtt);
header("Location: add_student_forum.php?signup=success".$id);
exit();
```

Make sure you have mysqli error reporting enabled. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)