# Filter then count and put the values to another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables the first table have regular price and discounted price. I'm trying to count how many regular price and discounted price and put the values in second table.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from

Answer (score 0):

Table_1
ID, someFields, Price, DiscountedPrice

Assumptions :

1. DiscountedPrice is 0 when no discount is given
2. Table 2 holds the number of elements with/without discount;

Table_2
Kind, CountValue, CountedOn

```
insert into Table_2 (Kind, CountValue, CountedOn)
Select 'Price', count(Id), GetDate()
from table1
Where DiscountedPrice=0
Union
Select 'Discount', count(Id), GetDate()
from table1
Where DiscountedPrice>0
```

==> Table_2

| Kind | CountValue | CountedOn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'Price' | 7 | 31-05-201 |
| 'Discount' | 3 | 31-05-201 |

---

Assumptions :

1. DiscountedPrice is 0 when no discount is given
2. Table 2 holds the number of elements with/without discount on given Date;

Table_2
Price, Discounted, CountedOn

```
insert into Table_2 (Price , Discounted, CountedOn)
Select ( select count(Id) from table1 Where DiscountedPrice=0 ) as Price , 
       ( select count(Id) from table1 Where DiscountedPrice>0 ) as Discounted, 
      getdate()
```

==> Table_2

| Price | Discounted | CountedOn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 1 | 25-05-201 |
| 7 | 3 | 31-05-201 |

Answer (score 0):

you can use count query to count the regular prices and discount price from the particular table like this

```
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM   employees
      ) AS regular_prices,
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM   departments
      ) AS discount_price
FROM table1
```

note: you ca also add where clause for particular condition base filtering.

and that count you can put using insert query to another table which is table2.