# How do insert data into a table that already exists?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert data into a table that already exists, but I cant find anything on how to do this. I only found how to insert this data into a new table.

> Syntax error at or near Insert

[Tutorial I visited](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-into/)

```
 SELECT film_category.film_id, film_category.category_id, rental_duration, rental_rate
 INSERT INTO category_description
 FROM film_category
 LEFT JOIN FILM
 ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
```

Comment: INSERT INTO category_description (film_id,category_id,rental_duration,rental_rate) SELECT film_category.film_id,film_category.category_id,rental_duration,rental_rate
  FROM film_category
 LEFT JOIN FILM
 ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id

Comment: Looks like you are looking for Update?

Comment: You don't need the SELECT to just insert data (if you want to modify existing data in the table, then you need an UPDATE).

Comment: Can you point me into the right direction? the table I'm trying to insert into is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified test to showcase methods to insert.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableA (
> ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
> ColA1 INT, 
> ColA2 VARCHAR(30)
> );
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- INSERT VALUES into existing table
> --
> INSERT INTO TableA (ColA1, ColA2) VALUES
> (10, 'A'),
> (20, 'B'), 
> (30, 'C');
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- SELECT INTO new table
> --
> SELECT ID, ColA1+2 AS ColB1, ColA2||'2' AS ColB2 
> INTO TableB
> FROM TableA;
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- INSERT from SELECT with explicit columns
> --
> INSERT INTO TableA (ColA1, ColA2) 
> SELECT ColB1+1, CONCAT(LEFT(ColB2,1),'3') AS ColB23
> FROM TableB;
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TableA;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cola1 | cola2
> -: | ----: | :----
>  1 |    10 | A    
>  2 |    20 | B    
>  3 |    30 | C    
>  4 |    13 | A3   
>  5 |    23 | B3   
>  6 |    33 | C3
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- INSERT from SELECT without columns
> -- Only works when they have the same number of columns. 
> --
> INSERT INTO TableB
> SELECT *
> FROM TableA;
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TableB;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | colb1 | colb2
> -: | ----: | :----
>  1 |    12 | A2   
>  2 |    22 | B2   
>  3 |    32 | C2   
>  1 |    10 | A    
>  2 |    20 | B    
>  3 |    30 | C    
>  4 |    13 | A3   
>  5 |    23 | B3   
>  6 |    33 | C3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=34ee295acc683fe6ecbaa1e793862e90)*

Answer (score 0):

The order is wrong https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Also see this answer
[Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from?rq=1)

```sql
 INSERT INTO category_description
 SELECT 
   film_category.film_id,
   film_category.category_id,
   rental_duration,
   rental_rate
 FROM 
   film_category
   LEFT JOIN FILM ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
```

Comment: this did not work

Comment: Are you inserting all columns or only a subset of columns? If you are inserting a subset of columns then you need to specify the columns as such INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;

Comment: Im inserting all columns from a join