# How to insert data into database in Room in Kotlin?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I'm creating an application. I wanted to add a feature where the user can click on a smiley face on the main screen, and when clicked, a new row will be inserted into the database with the following fields: id, emotion (a number from 1 to 5 corresponding to the selected smiley face), and the date of the click. The Room database structure seems to be built well, but the problem arises when I add the ViewModel responsible for inserting a new element into the database - the application fails to open. I'm not sure why this is happening. The Logcat is showing numerous errors. How can I insert data into the database after clicking the button?
To call the ViewModel for the homeScreen(), I was passing it from PsycheaScreen() in navigation, and previously in MainActivity. I also tried to create a separate screen for selecting emotions, but even after connecting the ViewModel, the application still wouldn't start.
Here is the project: https://github.com/M-ichael-M/Psychea20Days
The database logic is located in /data and /data/mood. The selection buttons are in ui/screens/home.kt, and the ViewModel is in ui/screens/tools/MoodViewModel.kt.
Please provide instructions on what I should do to correctly insert data into the database. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)